# Magento 1 URL rewrite Reindex takes forever and no data on core_url_rwrite table

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, reindex

We have a Magento 1.9.1 site with around 800k products. The core_url_rewrite table was truncated in order to get new url_rewrites after indexing.

The problem is the url_rewrite reindex is taking for 2 days already but there are no data found on the core_url_rewrite table. Also, when I open the rewrite table it shows 0-0 of 1,456,361 records found. This makes things even more complicated.

We updated the latest security patches before doing the reindex, is there any possibility that it affected the reindexing module?

Note: The server, 8 cores CPU, 30G RAM

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run indexing via ssh command-

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```

Comment: Yes of course I am running it on SSH cause were talking hundred of thousands of products here so there's now way it will work from the backend.